# How to interact with another programs with OLE Automation in C#?

Tags: c#, ole

I create an application with C# that can read item data from SQL Server and push it to the scale system named "SLP-V Ishida Retail Scales". They have an interface "SLP-V Automation Interface" that allows user programs to interact with their systems. This is the note from help page in SLP-V :

> The automation interface (also known as the "COM (common object model) interface") provides a method for user programs to access SLP-V functions. The most common application for this is the use of VB Script to automate SLP-V operations such as importing host files. However, the automation interface can be used from any programming environment that supports automation (COM), and this is the preferred method for incorporating SLP-V functions into end-user applications.
>
> This topic provides a reference for the methods and properties of the SLP-V automation object and includes some sample programs.
>
> **SLP-V Automation Object**
>
> The SLP-V automation object name is "Ishida.Slp.Scripting.CommonApi" and the type library file is "SlpScripting.tlb".

My question is, does the C# language allow us to interact other programs using OLE Automation? And if the answer is yes, how do I interact with my program? 
I mean like calling their method. Because I can't add `SlpScripting.tlb` as a reference. It says

> A reference  to 'SLP  Scripting Interface ' could not be added
>   The ActiveX type library  'SlpScripting.tlb' was exported  from a .NET  assembly and cannot  be added as reference. Add a reference to  the .NET assembly instead

And I have searched Google about this, but I didn't find the answer.

---

**Finally found a solution**
I don't have to add reference in c#, instead of just using :

```
System.Type objType = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("The name of progID that you want to call"); 
dynamic comObject = System.Activator.CreateInstance(objType);
```

- Example ProgID = "Ishida.Slp.Scripting.CommonApi".

And then just call the function / method that exist in that object, for example :

```
comObject.LoginToHost("localhost", 8085, username, pass);
```

---

Comment: Do they really not have anything else in that help page about accessing their system from .NET code? Because that error is indicating that their stuff is written in .NET as well, and the system doesn't want to have to round trip everything through two sets of wrappers (translate .NET -> COM and then translate COM -> .NET)

Comment: I have read the Help Documentation, but there aren't mention how to access their system from C# .NET Code. If i make this program in Visual Basic, can it be more easy to interact with the SLP System? Because it mention inside "ScaleLink Pro supports ActiveX automation (also known as OLE automation). This allows ScaleLink Pro operations to be controlled by external programs, including programs written in scripting languages such as Visual Basic and Java script."

Answer (score 3):

OLE automation is old wording for what we now call COM. And yes, .NET can access COM very easily (starting with .NET 1.0).

You have these options:

**Method 1**

First "register" the COM library on your development system. Look in the documentation of the SLP system, probably this was done already during setup. If not, normally a COM DLL can be registered manually with regsvr32 XXX.DLL. Be aware of 32/64 Bit issues (if you want to register a 32 bit COM DLL in 64 bit Windows, use `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe`).

Then your COM DLL should be listed in Visual Studio if you go to

Add Reference ==> COM

as "SlpScripting Type Library 1.0" or similar.

Then, add a "using SLPxxxx" or similar (Intellisense should show the real name).

After this, you should be able to create a new instance of your COM object.

For additional help, search for "C# COM interop", you will find lots of informations.

**Method 2**

Open a Visual Studio command prompt, and enter:

```
tlbimp SlpScripting.tlb
```

A DLL will be created, which you can add as a reference.

Comment: First, thank you for your explanation.
In method 1 that you mention, it already been registered inside the COM library and the name is "SLP Scripting Interface". It is just the same as SlpScripting.tlb that i have mention before and when i add it, it show me an error like "A reference to 'SLP Scripting Interface ' could not be added...." 

In method 2, i have done it before. But, still shows me an error "TlbImp : error TI1029 : Type library 'SlpScripting' was exported from a CLR assembly and cannot be re-imported as a CLR assembly."

this makes me so confused. But thanks for the answer :)